# Logarithmic inequality with different log bases

Tags: calculus, logarithms

[Here is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMg4X.png)

I rearranged the formula to be $x^2-2x+1=4^{\log_2(3)}$

I ended up factoring and solving for $x$ getting $x=4$ and $x=-2$. Is what I did correct?

Thanks!

Comment: The original problem is an inequality !!

Answer (score 1):

It's $$\log_2|x-1|<\log_23$$ or
$|x-1|<3$ and $x\neq1$.

The first inequality gives $-2<x<4$, which gives the answer:
$$(-2,1)\cup(1,4)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\log(x^2-2x+1)}{\log 4} \lt \dfrac{\log 3}{\log 2}$

$\dfrac{\log(x^2-2x+1)}{2\log 2} \lt \dfrac{\log 3}{\log 2}$

$\log(x^2-2x+1) \lt 2 \log 3$

$\log(x^2-2x+1) \lt \log 9$

$(x^2-2x+1) \lt 9$

The solution space is $(-2,1)\cup(1,4)$

x = 1 is excluded as the log of 0 is undefined.

Comment: (a) In MathJax (or LaTeX) use commands with backslash to enter names of standard functions. For example, `\log` produces $\log$ in the right script. (b) Try plugging in $x=1$ from your "solution" into the original inequality...

Comment: very good point!!.

Comment: If you're helping someone else, you should explain to them why exactly $x=1$ has to be excluded...

Comment: Fixed Sir, small points make a big difference

Answer (score 0):

Observe how bases can be changed eg $\log_4 16$ = $\log_2 4$

$\log_4 (x^2-2x+1) < \log_2 3$

$\log_4 (x^2-2x+1) < \log_4 9$

$x^2-2x+1 < 9$

$x^2-2x-8 < 0$

$(x-4)(x+2)<0$

Test: For x = 0, the equation is true.

Ans = $-2<x<4$

Comment: (a) It's an inequality, not an equation. (b) Writing "Ans = (an inequality)" is a terrible misuse of the equals sign. (c) Try plugging in $x=1$ from your "solution" into the original inequality...

Comment: your (a) and (b) refer to the same thing